# How to redirect path using nginx while removing part of the path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Using nginx 1.8.1 on CentOS Linux, I am attempting to do the following:

- Redirect traffic from `server_name server1.olddomain.com;` to `server2.newdomain.com`
- In doing so, remove `sites` from the path.

For example, a modified snippet from `nginx.conf`.

```
server {
   ...
   server_name server1.olddomain.com;
   ...
   location /sites/ITDept {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://server2.newdomain.com/ITDept;
}
```

While this does work as expected for the exact rule above, anything else does not work.

`https://server1.olddomain.com/sites/ITDept/subfolder/subfolder` does not redirect as desired as `https://server2.newdomain.com/ITDept/subfolder/subfolder`.  It redirects to `https://server2.newdomain.com/sites/ITDept/subfolder/subfolder`.

I've spent hours trying to figure out the correct syntax without success.  I hope that there is someone that can be of assistance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I may have just figured it out.
By modifying the rewrite rule to this:

`rewrite ^/sites/(.*)$ https://server2.newdomain.com/$1 last;`

Seems to do the trick.  Unless anyone has a better alternative.  I'm still testing many links to determine if this is going to work, but so far so good. Thanks to this article. [How to quick and easy remove part of an URL in Nginx with HttpRewriteModule?](https://serverfault.com/questions/302509/how-to-quick-and-easy-remove-part-of-an-url-in-nginx-with-httprewritemodule)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with URIs which do not begin with `/sites`, but a simple `rewrite` should be all that is required:

```
server {
    server_name server1.olddomain.com;
    rewrite ^/sites(.*)$ https://server2.newdomain.com$1 permanent;
    return 404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.